# How to get the display function in GLUT?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Is there a GLUT function I can call to get a pointer to the current displayFunc?

EX:

```
glutDisplayFunc(0xABC);
glutGetDisplayFunc(); // returns 0xABC
```

Comment: Maybe I have something to learn. But if you assigned the callback you would know it already. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Like @lakeweb suggests, the display function registration is the responsibility of the application, there is no default display function when the window is created. You can also not pass NULL as a display function, which means all registered functions are constructed at the application side. Are you hacking into a closed codebase or somesuch?

Comment: Haha, yes, in a perfect world this is true @lakeweb. I'm writing a OpenGL hook, and would be really nice to simply get the OpenGL display func by calling a glut function. Also, I need something that works after initialization (one could hook glutDisplayFunc and wait for it to be called, but this is a nuisance).

Comment: If you must, then use one of the GLUT open source alternatives and hack it. I'm still not sure why you need this.

Comment: @BillRichard: What is your "OpenGL hook" going to do with programs that don't use GLUT?  There is no such thing as an "OpenGL display func", this is a concept that only exists at the level of the wrapper (e.g. GLUT).

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no such function to get the current callback functions such as display functions, as you can see in [glut Api documentaion](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node1.html). The glut get functions are meant for state retrieval.